# Where are the Crawling.log files in Sitecore Managed Hosting?

Tags: logging, sitecore-managed-cloud

We have a Sitecore 9.3 solution hosted in Sitecore Managed Cloud and due to an issue with indexing jobs getting stuck for 24+ hours, we would like to look at the `Crawling.log.{date}.{time}.txt` files - which do not appear to exist where they should, and queried Application Insights which does not appear to have anything for the Crawling log.

The `admin/showconfig` page shows what we expect:

```
<appender name="CrawlingLogFileAppender" patch:source="Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.config" type="Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.Logging.Log4NetAppender, Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights">
    <file value="d:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\App_Data/logs/Crawling.log.{date}.{time}.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <encoding value="utf-8"/>
    <category value="crawling" patch:source="Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.config"/>
</appender>
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Crawling" additivity="false" patch:source="Foundation.Logging.Production.config">
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CrawlingLogFileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AzureFallbackAppender" desc="AzureFallbackAppender" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceContentManagement.Administration.config"/>
</logger>
```

We have some custom log files that are in the same folder `/site/wwwroot/App_Data/logs`, and the regular Sitecore logs are in nested folders that appear to have the worker process ID like `/site/wwwroot/App_Data/logs/WKN00000000Z` for example.

The question is... where are the log files going? Is there some additional configuration necessary because we aren't seeing any of the normal additional log files (e.g., Crawling, Search, Client, Aggregation, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore writes log information to `Microsoft Application Insights` when running on the `Microsoft Azure App Service`.

In Application Insights, you can identify error and warning messages, identify messages from specific roles and Sitecore instances, and search for specific log messages.

Microsoft Azure Application Insights is an extensible application performance management (APM) service that Sitecore uses to analyze logs and filter on searches, (this is because all Sitecore instances in a Sitecore environment share the same Application Insights resources).

Search Sitecore logs using Application Insights

1. Go to the `Microsoft Azure Portal` and log on.
2. On the `Dashboard`, click `All resources`, and select your Sitecore installation from the list of provisioned Azure resources.
3. Click the `Application Insights` resource. When the page opens, on the toolbar, click Search.
4. In the Search panel that appears on the right side, type your key search words in the Search box and click Enter.
5. At the top of the Search panel, click Filters.
6. In the Filter panel that appears on the right side, under `Event Types`, clear all of the checkboxes except for the `Trace` and `Exception` checkboxes.
7. To see the `Trace events`, at the bottom of the panel, click `Update`.

Read more details and other ways to see logs: [Analyze Sitecore logs with Application Insights](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/analyze-sitecore-logs-with-application-insights.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the general information. Like the question says, we have already queried Application Insights and aren't seeing anything. We have the log level set to "WARN" so it's possible no warnings or errors are happening. We will keep digging. Thanks again.